# Make onPressed wait for ads to be loaded

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-onpressed

let me tell you the process I want and what is happening

**Process:**
Press the `ElevatedButton` then show `adScreenLoadingDialog` till `_isAdLoaded=true` then display the ad and go to the next screen.

**What is happening: there are two conditions:**

**First**, if the user opens the screen and scrolls or waits for maybe 5 seconds, Then clicks on `ElevatedButton`, The process works fine everything is ok.

**Second**, if the user opens the screen and clicks on `ElevatedButton` immediately, Then  `adScreenLoadingDialog` appears but the process stops because `_isAdLoaded` is not true yet and the process goes wrong.

**What I need your help for:**
How to make `onPressed` display `adScreenLoadingDialog` and wait till `_isAdLoaded` become true so the ad is ready to display and go to the next screen.

I tried to use while loop but it didn't work.

I really appreciate it if someone could help.

Thanks

This is my screen code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class BusTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BusTestState createState() => _BusTestState();
}

class _BusTestState extends State<BusTest> {
  ////////////////////ADS////////////////
  InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;
  bool _isAdLoaded = false;

  ///ToDo  Interstitial Ad Unite
  void _initAd() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712',
      request: AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: onAdLoaded,
        onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
          print(error);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void onAdLoaded(InterstitialAd ad) {
    _interstitialAd = ad;
    _isAdLoaded = true;
    _interstitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
        _initAd();
        //_interstitialAd.dispose();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, error) {
        _initAd();
        //_interstitialAd.dispose();
      },
    );
  }

  ////////////////////ADS////////////////

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initAd();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Bus Test",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 16),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      maximumSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) {
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                            return Size(double.infinity, 60);
                          }
                          return Size(double.infinity, 60);
                        },
                      ),
                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(0)),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) {
                          // If the button is pressed, return green, otherwise blue
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                            return Color(0xff795368);
                          }
                          return Color(0xff3E2A35);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      adScreenLoadingDialog(context);
                      if (_isAdLoaded) {
                        await _interstitialAd.show();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => BusTest1(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Bus Test 1',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      maximumSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) {
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                            return Size(double.infinity, 60);
                          }
                          return Size(double.infinity, 60);
                        },
                      ),
                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(0)),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) {
                          // If the button is pressed, return green, otherwise blue
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                            return Color(0xff795368);
                          }
                          return Color(0xff3E2A35);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      adScreenLoadingDialog(context);
                      if (_isAdLoaded) {
                        await _interstitialAd.show();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => BusTest2(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Bus Test 2',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      maximumSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) {
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                            return Size(double.infinity, 60);
                          }
                          return Size(double.infinity, 60);
                        },
                      ),
                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(0)),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) {
                          // If the button is pressed, return green, otherwise blue
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                            return Color(0xff795368);
                          }
                          return Color(0xff3E2A35);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      adScreenLoadingDialog(context);
                      if (_isAdLoaded) {
                        await _interstitialAd.show();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => BusTest3(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Bus Test 3',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

adScreenLoadingDialog(context) {
  return showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          content: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: SpinKitCircle(
              color: Color(0xffd88820),
              size: 100,
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

so

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to make `onPressed` display `adScreenLoadingDialog` and wait till `_isAdLoaded` become `true`, you can use this `Function` to add delays until `_isAdLoaded` is `true`.

```
 Future<void> checkIfAdLoaded() async {
    if (_isAdLoaded) {
      return;
    } else {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      checkIfAdLoaded();
    }
  }
```

Add it to `onPressed` like this,

```
                    onPressed: () async {
                      adScreenLoadingDialog(context);
                      checkIfAdLoaded();
                      if (_isAdLoaded) {
                        await _interstitialAd.show();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => BusTest2(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
```

You can also use use a `Completer` but that would need more code changes.

Also, wrap `_isAdLoaded = true;` in `setState((){})`,

```
void onAdLoaded(InterstitialAd ad) {
  setState((){
    _interstitialAd = ad;
    _isAdLoaded = true;
  });
  _interstitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
    onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
      _initAd();
      //_interstitialAd.dispose();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, error) {
      _initAd();
      //_interstitialAd.dispose();
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it work and didn't work :D, It works fine if the ad loads fast, but if the network is slow or the ad didn't load fast, any reason makes some delay, it stuck and we return to the same issue. If there is any other solution it would be great. Thanks

Comment: thanks for your help, but I got the same as my last comment, if the network is slow or the ad didn't load fast, any reason makes some delay, it stuck and we return to the same issue, Is there any way to fix it using loop?